# bsi.production.order has no attribute 'isbn' - Odoo v8 - new api

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have these two classes:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
_name = 'bsi.production.order'

name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
production_type = fields.Selection([
        ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
        ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
        ('direct','Direct Order'),
    ], string='Type of Order', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")
notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")
warehouse_quantity = fields.Char(compute='quantity', string='Quantity per warehouse')

class bsi_production_order_lines(models.Model):
_name = 'bsi.production.order.lines'

production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', string="Production Orders")
isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity")
consumed_qty = fields.Float(string="Consumed quantity")
remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity")
```

So, from bsi.production.order, I access bsi.production.order.lines through order_lines field.

I need to check for isbn, which is actually a product, check how much there is on stock locations, then compare it, to the order_lines field qty, to see if there is enough quantity.

This is my method:

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.qty', 'order_lines.isbn')
def check_quantity(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.order_lines:
            for line in rec.order_lines:
                if line.qty > rec.isbn.qty_available:
                    raise Warning(('Quantity is invalid.'))
```

But everytime I click on this button it throws me:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 501, in check_quantity
AttributeError: 'bsi.production.order' object has no attribute 'isbn'
```

I know isbn is on `bsi.production.order.lines` object, and not `bsi.production.order`, but I have the constrains decorator which should take care of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that issue in the field you have define `ISBN ` `bsi.production.order.lines` inside domain `is_isbn` is not define anywhere in your model

Comment: Hi, it is defined on product.product, it actually works perfectly on the model itself, but not on the method

Comment: But why you add domain `domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]"` ? `is_isbn` field not defined anywhere in your model.

Comment: It is defined on product.product, it functions properly, but as I said, on the model itself (bsi.production.order.lines) that is just a filter, isbn is a Many2one to product.product

Comment: OK got it issue in line `if line.qty > rec.isbn.qty_available:` , here `rec` is of object  `bsi.production.order` so you have to change it to `if line.qty > line.isbn.qty_available:`

Comment: Thank You very much, You can put this as an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are accessing the order record not the line:

```py
@api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.qty', 'order_lines.isbn')
def check_quantity(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.order_lines:
            for line in rec.order_lines:
                # here the isbn is in line not rec because rec is the record
                if line.qty > line.isbn.qty_available:
                    raise Warning(('Quantity is invalid.'))
```

Comment: # and remove `@api.multi` from the decorators `@api.constrains, depends, ...` because it's by default

Comment: it was my fault earlier

Comment: Thank You very much :), Nice